# Página mostrando interrogação e banco mostrando acento?

Tags: php, acentuação

Na minha página, se eu digitar algum acento dentro de alguma tag, é mostrado normal;
Se eu envio algum acento via formulário para o banco, na tabela aparece (Ã¡) e na página aparece o acento normal. (á);
Se eu insiro diretamente na tabela um dado com acento Ex: (á), no banco aparece (á) e no site aparece o interrogação. (�)
Como faço para mostrar acento em tudo?
Estou usando PHP e mysql.

Comment: Tanto o banco quanto o site estão UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve verificar qual `ENCODING` está utilizando no HTML e no banco de dados, e fazer as alterações necessárias para usar o mesmo `ENCODING` nos dois.

O mais recomendado atualmente é usar UTF-8 para evitar dores de cabeça (pode ler mais a respeito [aqui](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/))

---

Então no HTML você define UTF-8 usando a tag meta conforme exemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
// resto do código
```

No MySQL você pode verificar o `ENCODING` atual com a query (fonte [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049958/2312615)):

```
SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA 
WHERE schema_name = "schemaname";
```

---

Caso seu banco de dados não esteja em UTF-8, você terá duas opções:

- Definir o mesmo encoding do banco de dados nas páginas HTML
- Atualizar o banco de dados para usar UTF-8

Confesso que atualizar o `ENCODING` do banco de dados pode ser um pouco chato, mas acho melhor do que usar outro `ENCODING`.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de inserir os dados no banco é preciso utilizar o padrão UTF8, tente da seguinte maneira;

$VARIAVEL = UTF8_decode("TEXTO");

feito isso você já pode inserir os dados no banco, caso não tenha funcionado será preciso verificar o padrão a qual seu banco está configurado e alterar para o mesmo padrão da sua pagina.
[Documentação PHP.](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Opa...

Você pode fazer isto de várias maneiras...
Pode definir no próprio PHP, colocando no início do documento

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

Pode agilizar a saída dos dados direto da conexão no **MySQL**:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

**PDO**:

```
$handle = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nomebanco",
'usuario', 'senha',
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Caso o problema esteja acontecendo apenas com o **HTML**, resolve-se simplesmente definindo o UTF da página, ou o **UTF-8** ou o código **ISO-8859-1**...

Pode também fazer da forma mais difícil, com o **str_replace**:

```
$string="Téstè! Hasta Mañana!";
function retiraAcentos($string){
return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|`ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/"),explode(" ","a A e E i I o O u U n N"),$string);
```

}`

```
echo retiraAcentos($string);
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma :)